# Swapping two ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write code for swapping two ranges:

```
Sub SwapRanges()
  Dim range1 As Range
  Dim range2 As Range
  Dim holder As Range

  range1 = Range("D7:D12")
  range2 = Range("E7:E12")
  holder = Range("F7:F12")

  Set holder = range1
  Set range1 = range2
  Set range2 = holder
End Sub
```

but get *run-time error 91*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the error is that you are not using the `Set` command when assigning ranges. In addition, understand that this code:

```
Set holder = range1
Set range1 = range2
Set range2 = holder
```

only changes the ranges referred to by the variables `holder`, `range1`, and `range2`. It doesn't actually copy the data contained in those references from one range to another.

The code below will perform the actual copying while also addressing the run-time error.

```
Sub SwapRanges()
  Dim range1 As Range
  Dim range2 As Range
  Dim holder As Range

  Set range1 = Range("D7:D12")
  Set range2 = Range("E7:E12")
  Set holder = Range("F7:F12")

  range1.Copy holder
  range2.Copy range1
  holder.Copy range2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this way (sorry, non tested - writing from a Chrombook :)

```
Sub SwapRanges()
  Dim range1 As Range
  Dim range2 As Range
  Dim holder() as variant

  Set range1 = Range("D7:D12")
  Set range2 = Range("E7:E12")

  holder = range1    
  range1 = range2
  range2 = holder
End Sub
```

Comment: i assume this wasn't tested?

Comment: @ashleedawg No need to assume 3 years later. It's written black on white on the very first line.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coping you can just say:
       holder=range1
       Range2=range1
       Holder=range2

Not realy related to the question pnuts answered it but I thought this would be helpful for your application.

Comment: i assume this wasn't tested?