# Swap two ranges VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to swap two ranges. I've tried the method shown in [another post on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924905/swapping-two-ranges) but I still can't do it. I get errors such as well.. 'nothing happens' with this code :

(these are big code samples but the swapping part is pretty small at the end. I have put a comment to indicate the location of it. Temp variable is defined at the beginning)

Or `execution error '5' : Argument or procedure call incorrect` (it appears on the first line of my swapping process) with this code:

```
Dim X, Y, Xi, Yi, Ligne As Integer
Dim Temp As Range              ''Here is a change I make
For iLine = 3 To LastLine
    If .Cells(iLine, 5) = "Line" Then
        Y = .Cells(iLine, 8).Value
        X = .Cells(iLine, 7).Value
    ElseIf .Cells(iLine, 5) = "Arc" Then
        X = .Cells(iLine, 15).Value
        Y = .Cells(iLine, 16).Value
    End If

    Ligne = iLine + 1
    Do While Ligne <= LastLine
        If .Cells(Ligne, 5) = "Line" Then
            Xi = .Cells(Ligne, 9).Value
            Yi = .Cells(Ligne, 10).Value
        ElseIf .Cells(Ligne, 5) = "Arc" Then
            Xi = .Cells(Ligne, 17).Value
            Yi = .Cells(Ligne, 18).Value
        End If
   '''''Swapping is here
        If (X = Xi) And (Y = Yi) Then 
            Range(.Cells(Ligne, 6), .Cells(Ligne, 18)).Copy Temp               ''Here is a change I make and where the error occurs
            Range(.Cells(iLine + 1, 6), .Cells(iLine + 1, 18)).Copy Range(.Cells(Ligne, 6), .Cells(Ligne, 18))
            Range(.Cells(iLine + 1, 6), .Cells(iLine + 1, 18)) = Temp
            Exit Do
        Else
            Ligne = Ligne + 1
        End If
    Loop
Next iLine
```

P.S : to explain what I'm doing : I'm trying to reorganize a sheet that I have. this sheets contains in and out coordinates but these coordinates don't currently follow each other.

So I'm comparing in and out entries to reorganize them in a way that each out coordinates is the same in coordinates as the next entry.

Here is the data I have :
[image: Data sample]

---

---

**EDIT :**

I'm now stuck here. The function posted by @ashleedawg empties my cells. So I tried to implement her method but directly into my own code. But this time back to the first fail, it does nothing. I'm thinking this might be because of the other part of my code so if you see anything wrong please let me know :

```
Dim X, Y, Xi, Yi As Double
Dim Ligne As Integer
Dim Temp, rg1, rg2 As Range
For iLine = 3 To LastLine
    If .Cells(iLine, 5) = "Line" Then
        X = .Cells(iLine, 9).Value
        Y = .Cells(iLine, 10).Value
    ElseIf .Cells(iLine, 5) = "Arc" Then
        X = .Cells(iLine, 17).Value
        Y = .Cells(iLine, 18).Value
    End If

    Ligne = iLine + 1
    Do While Ligne <= LastLine
        If .Cells(Ligne, 5) = "Line" Then
            Xi = .Cells(Ligne, 7).Value
            Yi = .Cells(Ligne, 8).Value
        ElseIf .Cells(Ligne, 5) = "Arc" Then
            Xi = .Cells(Ligne, 15).Value
            Yi = .Cells(Ligne, 16).Value
        End If

        If (Xi = X) And (Yi = Y) Then
            Set Temp = Range(.Cells(1000, 1000), .Cells(1000, 1012))
            Set rg1 = Range(.Cells(Ligne, 6), .Cells(Ligne, 18))
            Set rg2 = Range(.Cells(iLine + 1, 6), .Cells(iLine + 1, 18))
            rg1.Copy Temp
            rg2.Copy rg1
            Temp.Copy rg2
            'SwapRanges Range(.Cells(iLine + 1, 6), .Cells(iLine + 1, 18)), Range(.Cells(Ligne, 6), .Cells(Ligne, 18))
            Exit Do
        Else
            Ligne = Ligne + 1
        End If
    Loop
Next iLine
```

The last item I have in my temp range is the last line of my sheet :

```
Arc 50  120         50  46,834  180 5   84,206  156,469 0   120
```

Comment: @ashleedawg I use a temp variable. In the second bloc of code it is defined as Range (in the first bloc i use Variant). They all have the same size.

Comment: @ashleedawg sorry I'm adding that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sub `SwapRanges` will swap the two cell ranges that you give it.

It has no error handling (yet), mainly to ensure that the ranges are the same size and shape (rows x columns) but I will can add that after. Also functionality could theoretically be added to prompt you to select (highlight) the first range and then choose the beginning of the second range.  OR, if the range are *always* going to be the same size then the sub could be changed to only specify the starting cell and the ending cell...

But for now:

```
Sub SwapRanges(rg1 As Range, rg2 As Range)
    Const SwapRC = 1000 ' unused cells to temporaily house the data. (row 1000, col 1000)
    Dim rgLimbo As Range

    Set rgLimbo = Range(Cells(SwapRC, SwapRC), Cells(SwapRC + rg1.Rows.Count, SwapRC + rg1.Columns.Count))
    rg1.Copy rgLimbo       'copy rg1 to "limbo"
    rg2.Copy rg1           'copy rg2 to rg1
    rgLimbo.Copy rg2       'copy "limbo" to rg1
    rgLimbo.ClearContents  'clear "limbo"
End Sub
```

...so for example I tested it on my end with these two ranges and everything including cell formatting was swapped back and forth repeatedly.

```
Sub Example()
    SwapRanges Range("B2:D8"), Range("F6:H9")
End Sub
```

It uses a "limbo" cell location as a temporary "holder", beginning at Row 1000, Column 1000. If you have existing data there you'll want to change the constant.

---

- Here's an example of it working for me... (I just assigned sub `Example` to the button.)

  [image: img]

Comment: It doesn't work for me... It just empties my cells so I'm checking the rest of my code to see where is the problem

Comment: @JackA alright - now this is a mission for me.. :-)   Which parameters did you specify when you ran the procedure?

Comment: I've found my mistake this is actually a very dumb mistake. When I test Line or Arc like this `If .Cells(Ligne, 5) = "Line" Then` it is not column 5 but 6.... I've manage to find this mistake by replacing letters by numbers on my excel sheet. Thank you for your help though. Your code helped me get something cleaner than what I previously had !

Comment: Hooray! I'm glad you figured it out.  Don't feel bad, the most annoying coding mistakes are rarely "smart" ones. ( I could tell you some *screen-smashingly dumb* mistakes I've been stuck on for weeks.)  now that you mention how you figured it out, i realized a troubleshooting step i could have mentioned a lot earlier... Next time, *step through the code* with F8 to see what it's doing. Read more about that here:  **[Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)**.  (Perhaps bookmark that link - Guru Chip's site is my #1 favourite resource for VBA-Everything)

Comment: Thank you for the source ! :) I'll dig into it if I ever get stuck again !

Comment: What didn't work when I used your function has been solved with @user2815201 's answer below ! Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after I changed this line

```
Set rgLimbo = Range(Cells(SwapRC, SwapRC), Cells(SwapRC + rg1.Rows.Count, SwapRC + rg1.Columns.Count))
```

to this

```
Set rgLimbo = Range(Cells(SwapRC, SwapRC), Cells(SwapRC + rg1.Rows.Count-1, SwapRC + rg1.Columns.Count-1))
```